# xyzzyで((4 1 . #1=(2 . #2=(3))) (1 4 . #1#) (1 2 4 . #2#) (1 2 3 4))は普通のリストで表示されない

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, lisp, xyzzy

このようなコードを作成しましたが、結果は普通なリストになっていませんでした。

```
(defun ins (x f s)
  (cons
   (append f (cons x s))
   (if (null s)
       nil
     (ins x
          (reverse (cons (car s) (reverse f)))
          (cdr s)))))
```

実行結果：

```
(ins 4 nil '(1 2 3))
((4 1 . #1=(2 . #2=(3))) (1 4 . #1#) (1 2 4 . #2#) (1 2 3 4))
```

同じコードをemacsで実行した場合、問題がなかったです。

```
(ins 4 nil '(1 2 3))
((4 1 2 3) (1 4 2 3) (1 2 4 3) (1 2 3 4))
```

xyzzyでemacsと同じ結果になれないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

`#1=` `#1#` というのはCommon Lisp系Lispでは同じデータを参照していることを示す表示です。  
xyzzyはCommon Lispに六割程度準拠とのことですが、Common Lispであれば、 `*print-circle*` を `nil` に設定することで、共有構造の表示を無効にできます。

```lisp
(setq *print-circle* nil)

(ins 4 nil '(1 2 3))
→ ((4 1 2 3) (1 4 2 3) (1 2 4 3) (1 2 3 4))
```

しかし、上記をxyzzyで試したところ、この設定は有効にならないようです(バグ?)

今回の場合は、同じセルデータを共有していることが明示されているだけですので、`ins` が出力するデータの内容については変わりありません。

```lisp
(equal '((4 1 . #1=(2 . #2=(3))) (1 4 . #1#) (1 2 4 . #2#) (1 2 3 4))
       '((4 1 2 3) (1 4 2 3) (1 2 4 3) (1 2 3 4)))
→ t
```

なお発想を転換して、構造を共有しないことにすれば(使い回しではなく毎度新規に作成する)、当然ながら共有構造の表示はされなくなります。

```lisp
(defun ins (x f s)
  (cons
   (append (copy-tree f) (cons x (copy-tree s)))
   (if (null s)
       nil
       (ins x
            (reverse (cons (car s) (reverse f)))
            (cdr s)))))
```

```lisp
(ins 4 '((a) (b) (c)) '(1 2 3 (4)))
→ (((a) (b) (c) 4 1 2 3 (4))
   ((a) (b) (c) 1 4 2 3 (4))
   ((a) (b) (c) 1 2 4 3 (4))
   ((a) (b) (c) 1 2 3 4 (4))
   ((a) (b) (c) 1 2 3 (4) 4))
```

上記では、`copy-tree`で、リスト`f`と`s`をディープコピーしています。

Comment: 補足： xyzzy では評価式の出力を行う際に `*print-circle*=t` をハードコードしているため外部で変数を変更しても無効化されるようです（なのでバグ？というより仕様に近い）。https://github.com/xyzzy-022/xyzzy/blob/5a16eb998470241b33ad3caa6a4946d0448a16b6/lisp/lispmode.l#L348